# Arranging text in multiples columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to organize a balance sheet from a PDF to Excel. I pasted the whole line in one cell. Then, I managed to distinct the text from the value results. I pasted the text on B column and tryied to distribute the values along the other columns. Can someone help me out?

```
Sub adjustingRow()

   Dim subjectCell As String
   Dim letters As String
   Dim index As Integer
   Dim text As String
   Dim values(1 To 7) As String

   letters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklçzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLÇZXCVBNM "
   subjectCell = Range("A6").Value

   For i = 1 To Len(subjectCell)

       If InStr(1, letters, Mid(subjectCell, i + 1, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
           index = i
           Exit For
       End If

   Next i

   text = Left(subjectCell, index)
   values() = Split(Right(subjectCell, Len(subjectCell) - index), " ", -1, vbTextCompare)

   Range("B6").Value = text
   For j = 1 To 7
       ActiveCell.Offset(0, j).Range("A1").Value = values(j)
   Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What exactly is going wrong with your code?

Comment: I got the values() highlighted and the compilation error: "Can't assign to an array".

Comment: ah, yes, `Values` should be dimmed without specified size. `Dim values() As String`. The `Split` function will then resize it according to its result.

Comment: ... and `For j = 1 To 7` should be `For j = lbound(values) To ubound(values)` with `ActiveCell.Offset(0, j+1)` inside the loop. Unless you've added `Option Base 1` to the declarations section of the code sheet, *values* will be zero-based.

Answer (score 0):

Guys in the comments solved my problem. Here it goes:

Sub adjustingRow()

```
Dim subjectCell As String
Dim letters As String
Dim index, spacesBeforeIndex As Integer
Dim text As String
Dim values() As String

letters = "àáéíóãõqwertyuiopasdfghjklçzxcvbnmÀÁÉÍÓÃÕQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLÇZXCVBNM ,.!?"
subjectCell = ActiveCell.Value

For i = 1 To Len(subjectCell)

    If InStr(1, letters, Mid(subjectCell, i + 1, 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        index = i
        Debug.Print index
        Exit For
    End If

Next i

text = Left(subjectCell, index)
values() = Split(Right(subjectCell, Len(subjectCell) - index), " ", -1, vbTextCompare)

ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Value = text
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
For j = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
    values(j) = Replace(values(j), ".", ",")
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, j + 1).Range("A1").Value = values(j)
Next j

ActiveCell.Offset(1, -1).Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```